# Namespace issue in the XML payload POSTing to WCF REST service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, rest

I'm receiving a 400 bad request error w/ the following code:

**This is my WCF service contract**

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/cust_key/{key}/prod_id/{id}", 
           Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Stream GetData(string key, string id, XElment data);
```

The following xml payload **will work** and a 200 will be returned

```
<Product>
  <Name>laptop</Name>
</Product>
```

BUT this xml below w/ a **non-default** namespace will cause a **400 error**

```
<Productxsi:type="electronics" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>laptop</Name>
</Product>
```

How should I handle this namespace issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a silly thing: I escaped the quote in the xml and now it's working...sorry about this silly question. Hopefully this in some way can help somebody.